# RPi.GPIO: Can two applications toggle the same GPIO pin? (Accidentally or otherwise)

Tags: gpio

There's two applications, `A` and `B`.

`A` prepares to use a GPIO pin then starts doing its tasks.

After a while, `B` is also launched and prepares to use the same GPIO pin by `A`. A warning pops up, but this is only a warning.

```
RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
```

Could `B` also toggle the same GPIO pin, potentially damaging `A`'s work? What options do I have  to prevent this?

I would love to set up an experiment, but all my Pis are currently in use.

Comment: If this is a duplicate, feel free to flag and link me there. I could not find info about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can and will happen.

e.g. the following scripts both run concurrently and end up toggling the same GPIO.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

gpio=22

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(gpio, GPIO.OUT)

try:
   while True:
      GPIO.output(gpio, 1)
      time.sleep(0.1)

except:
   raise
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

gpio=22

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(gpio, GPIO.OUT)

try:
   while True:
      GPIO.output(gpio, 0)
      time.sleep(0.1)

except:
   raise
```

There is no way to prevent this.  A lot of the GPIO modules write to the GPIO registers directly for performance reasons.

The new `/dev/gpiochip` does prevent this situation for conforming applications as only one can claim a given GPIO at any one time.  However this doesn't help as the direct access modules do not conform.

Comment: Experimentally verified. Code review of a Python GPIO library also confirms it.